# How can I manage query parameters that are not always filled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-router

My model looks like this:

```
const replaySchema = new Schema({

    game: {type: String, required:true},
    link: {type: String, required:true,unique: true},
    player1: {type: String, required: true},
    player2: {type: String, required: true},
    character1: {type: String, required: true},
    character2: {type: String, required: true}


},{
    timestamps:true,
});
```

My user fills a form, with the same values as the model where he can leave empty most of the parameters, for example, he can only fill the game and the player1 field.

On submit of the form, a new const is created where it gets the parameters and values of the filled inputs in the form and then sends that to the backend in the `params` field.

```
onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const replay = {};

        this.state.game && (replay.game = this.state.game);
        this.state.player1 && (replay.player1 = this.state.player1);
        this.state.player2 && (replay.player2 = this.state.player2);
        this.state.character1 && (replay.character1 = this.state.character1);
        this.state.character2 && (replay.character2 = this.state.character2);

        console.log(replay);

        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/search/",
            {params:replay}).then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    replays: response.data
                })
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

And the backend was initially going to handle it like this.

```
router.route('/').get((req,res) => {

    console.log(req.query);

   Replay.find(req.query).then(replays => res.json(replays)).catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

However, we decided it's better if when the user enters a value in wichever player field, the db would return replays no matter if it was player1 or player2. Considering all the optional values, as you can see, there are many different queries that can come out from all the different options the user has with filling/not filling each value .

My first thought was to check which values are filled with ifs and make the different queries depending on that, but that would mean more than about 16 different queries, which doesn't sound too clean.

Then I thought about constructing a query string sequentially, but considering mongodb structure for $or and $in, trying to do it like that would almost like doing it with a lot of ifs.

Isn't there an easier way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: So you want to search for player1 or player2, no matter which one the user input? What if the inputs are switched? Would input `{ player1: 'A',  player2: 'B' }` match with `{ player1: 'B', player2: 'A' }` ? What about character1 & character2 ?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim exactly as you said with the players, and yes, the characters have to be "linked" to the player, wich complicates things even more. So when You look for ```{player1: 'A', character1:'C1'}``` the databse should return instances for ```{player1: 'A', character1:'C1'}``` AND ```{player2: 'A', character2:'C1'}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TomSlabbaert lead me in the right direction with the way I should handle queries for mongo db as arrays inside arrays.

Ultimately, the solution for my problem was this:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Replay = require('../models/Replay.model');

router.route('/').get((req,res) => {
   //console.log(req.query);
   let andConds = [];


   if (req.query.game) {
       andConds.push({game: req.query.game})
   }

   if (req.query.player1 || req.query.player2 || req.query.character1 || req.query.character2) {
       let orCondition = [];
       let stAndOrCondition =[];
       let ndAndOrCondition = [];
       if (req.query.player1) {
           stAndOrCondition.push({player1: req.query.player1})
           ndAndOrCondition.push({player2: req.query.player1})
       }

       if (req.query.player2) {
           stAndOrCondition.push({player2: req.query.player2})
           ndAndOrCondition.push({player1: req.query.player2})
       }

       if (req.query.character1) {
           stAndOrCondition.push({character1: req.query.character1})
           ndAndOrCondition.push({character2: req.query.character1})
       }
       if (req.query.character2) {
           stAndOrCondition.push({character2: req.query.character2})
           ndAndOrCondition.push({character1: req.query.character2})
       }
       orCondition.push({$and: stAndOrCondition})
       orCondition.push({$and: ndAndOrCondition})
       andConds.push({$or: orCondition})
       console.log(JSON.stringify(andConds))
   }



   //if no conditions exists match all as before.
   Replay.find(andConds.length ? {$and: andConds} : {}).then(replays => res.json(replays)).catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports= router;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to have your logic on the server side. And in this case it's not hard to achieve what you want.

Keep in my there's no generic "sexy" way to implement specific business. but there's no reason to be wary of implementing the logic to support it.

```
router.route('/').get((req,res) => {

    console.log(req.query);
    let andConds = [];

    if (req.query.character1) {
        andConds.push({character1: req.query.character1})
    }

    if (req.query.character2) {
        andConds.push({character2: req.query.character2})
    }

    if (req.query.game) {
        andConds.push({game: req.query.game})
    }

    if (req.query.player1 || req.query.player2) {
        let orCond = [];
        if (req.query.player1) {
            orCond.push({player1: req.query.player1})
            orCond.push({player2: req.query.player1})
        }

        if (req.query.player2) {
            orCond.push({player1: req.query.player2})
            orCond.push({player2: req.query.player2})
        }
        andConds.push({$or: orCond})
    }

    //if no conditions exists match all as before.
    Replay.find(andConds.length ? {$and: andConds} : {}).then(replays => res.json(replays)).catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

Comment: this answer helped me understand how to manage this kind of queries a lot, but there is still something you missed in your answer.
character1 and character2 field should also behave like player1 and player2, where if character1 is filled, the db should return instances where that character appears in character1 or 2, the problem is that it should be linked to the player, so if we filled fields player1:person and character1:character, the db should return all instances where person is in player1 AND character is in character1, AND person is in player2 AND character in character2.

Comment: The original logic did not do it so i just did it as is. Obviously just change whatever you need to in order for it to work as you expect.